# Появление выпадающего списка при клике - JS

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

При клике на `ПРОДУКЦИЯ/ПОРТФОЛИО` нужно, чтобы выпадало меню, и при повторном нажатии - обратно исчезало.
Нужно сделать методом JS. У меня получилось сделать так, чтобы меню появлялось, а как сделать, чтобы оно исчезало при повторном нажатии?

```js
var title = document.getElementById('title');
function show(){
  title.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.dropdown {
  height: 40px;
  width: 300px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #808080;
  height: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
.dropdown:hover h3 {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #a87f5c;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
 }

.dropdown_content {
   display: none;
   transition: all linear 0.3s;
   color: white;               
   background-color: #a87f5c;   
   padding: 1em;
   margin-left: 0.8em;
   margin-top: -20px;
   width: 190px;
   opacity: 0.98;
   height: 98px;
}
.dropdown_content a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;    
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    transition: .6s all ease;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.dropdown_content a:hover {
    color: white;
     margin-left: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
     <h3 href="pages/storage.html" onclick="show()">Продукция / портфолио</h3>
      <div class="dropdown_content" id="title">
          <a href="pages/tables.html">Столы</a>
          <a href="pages/storage.html">Мебель для хранения</a>
                 <a href="pages/interior.html">Интерьер</a>
                  <a href="pages/storage.html">Всё</a>
                </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```js
var title = document.getElementById('title');

function showHide() {
  if (title.style.display != 'block') { // если блок скрыт
    title.style.display = 'block'; // открываем его
  } else { // если открыт
    title.style.display = 'none'; // скрываем
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdown {
  height: 40px;
  width: 300px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #808080;
  height: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

.dropdown:hover h3 {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #a87f5c;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.dropdown_content {
  display: none;
  transition: all linear 0.3s;
  color: white;
  background-color: #a87f5c;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-left: 0.8em;
  margin-top: -20px;
  width: 190px;
  opacity: 0.98;
  height: 98px;
}

.dropdown_content a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  transition: .6s all ease;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropdown_content a:hover {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <h3 href="pages/storage.html" onclick="showHide()">Продукция / портфолио</h3>
  <div class="dropdown_content" id="title">
    <a href="pages/tables.html">Столы</a>
    <a href="pages/storage.html">Мебель для хранения</a>
    <a href="pages/interior.html">Интерьер</a>
    <a href="pages/storage.html">Всё</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: костыль немного

Comment: как же я люблю функциональное программирование